# Ошибка в setContentView при старте

Tags: android, kotlin

создаю проект с одним empty activity, собираю проект и запускаю на API 24, 26 в режиме дебага наблюдаю ошибку
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Wi2pnfjD)

Лог:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2609)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.kt:10)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2609)
        at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.kt:10)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Вот исходник:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот структура проекта:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.61"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

grandle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
```

ПС. 
Обратил внимание, что если наследоваться от Activity() а не от AppCompatActivity() то ошибка пропадает, но тогда не получается передать View в Snackbar (например)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: приложите ошибку в вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: Вы возможно не заметели, но я ссылка на pastebin почти в самом начале оставил, лог ошибки слишком большой по-этому сюда не вставил.

ПС. Вот ссылка => https://pastebin.com/Wi2pnfjD

Comment: я видел ссылку, приложите текст ошибки в вопрос!!!

Comment: У вас что-то странное. Покажите ещё разметку и `gradle.properties`

Comment: Добавил разметку и grandle.properties

Answer (score 0):

Не могу гарантировать решение проблемы. Но, вам стоит попробовать следующее:

1. Перейти в меню File
2. Выбрать Invalidate Caches / Restart...
3. Подтвердить действие включающее в себя обе функции Invalidate and Restart
4. После рестарта перейти в меню Build
5. Выбрать Clean Project, после окончания клина выбрать Rebuild Project

P.S. Верните наследование от AppCompatActivity()

P.S.S. Я создал дефолтный проект на котлине с вашими конфигурациями, запускается без каких-либо сбоев (запускал на эмуляторе с 27 апишкой)

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, но я нашел вроде что-то похожее на мою проблему => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782548/androidxappcompat-iart-error-android-view-viewonunhandledkeyeventlistener/52954286#52954286